# Hiding a div with checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've tried working with this but I think it is a problem with the jquery, my cloud9 thing says that '$ is not defined'

Here is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/qLuvsy9y/6/

Another example: http://jsfiddle.net/5udtC/6913/

```
       <div class="wanted"> <!-- Toggle Lowercase -->
        <label class="input-toggle">
         <input type="checkbox" id="isAgeSelected" checked>
          <span></span>
        </label>
       </div>
         <p>  Upper Lower Case Mix</p>

      <div class="hide">

         <div id="txtAge" style="display:none">
          <div class="wanted"> <!-- Toggle Uppercase -->
           <label class="input-toggle">
            <input type="checkbox" id="uppercase" checked>
             <span id="randomString"></span>
           </label>

           <p id="test1">Uppercase</p>
         </div>
```

Jquery

```
$('#isAgeSelected').change(function() {
    $("#hide").toggle(this.checked);
 });
```

Comment: Both of them are working fine?

Comment: Does your HTML contain the line `<script src="specify-path-to-jquery.js"></script>` in it somewhere?

Comment: your fiddles work because you have jQuery selected in your **frameworks & extensions** section.  In your own web site, you need to add the jQuery reference yourself

Comment: @TravelingTechGuy The ajax thing like this: https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/ ? or the actual javascript page. If the javascript page then yes, I forgot to include it

Comment: You forgot to close the bracket in the 1st example you posted. Besides that it works fine. https://jsfiddle.net/qLuvsy9y/8/

Answer (score 1):

if you cloud9 "thing" is saying $ is not defined then you are either not including the jquery library in your document or not wrapping your code in a document ready statement and the browser is trying to execute code too early.

you need to include the jquery library: either from a local file - such as:

```
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
```

or from a CDN - such as:

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and then you need to wrap the jquery in a document ready statement to ensure that the library has loaded before tying to execute jquery commands:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#isAgeSelected').change(function() {
        $("#hide").toggle(this.checked);
     });
});
```

and then you have a div with a class of "hide", but you are attempting to modify an element with an ID of "hide" in your code. These need to be the same:

```
$("#hide").toggle(this.checked);
```

should be

```
$(".hide").toggle(this.checked);
```

or change the div to be:

```
<div id="hide">
```

Comment: I changed my `<div class="hide">` to `<div id="hide">` and it still doesn't want to work. http://jsfiddle.net/5udtC/9623/

Comment: but you have an element within the di that contains the rest of the content and this is set to display:none ...<div id="txtAge" style="display:none">... so therefore the #hide might be displaying - but if the inner div (#txtAge)  is not because its set to display:none -  then there will be nothing in the div to display - so it will not appear on the screen. also - check all of your closing </div> tags and make sure that all opened <div>'s are closed